# Order By Date in table using Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using Visual Studio 2013 with Angular js.

My question is I am binding the data in table with ng-repeat like given example:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
  <tr class="box-head">
    <th><a href="#" ng-click="sortTypes = 'OrderNumber'; sortReverses = !sortReverses">OrderNo.</a></th>
    <th><a href="#" ng-click="sortTypes = 'OrderDate'; sortReverses = !sortReverses">Order DT.</a></th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="om in Data | orderBy:sortTypes:sortReverses">
    <td>{{om.OrderNumber}}</td>
    <td>{{om.OrderDate}}</td>
  <tr>
</table>
```

Here my sorting of data onclick of ordernumber is done perfectly fine but in orderdate sorting is not performed properly.

Am I doing wrong somewhere please guide me to do this! How to sort data onclick of OrderDate?

Any help will be appreciate. Thanks in advance.

Comment: is your orderDate formatted as date?

Comment: @Ladmerc No not formatted?

Comment: Either the original source needs to be date formatted or use angular's date filter to format as date

Comment: I can't understand what you are telling can you please give me reference or any jsfiddle? So I can understand. and yes I thing my date was already formatted.

Comment: You should provide a jsfiddle

Comment: Please check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/js64b/1582/) but here it runs fine but in my code I have done the same but not running

Comment: then post your code here!

Comment: the code is same as I have posted.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, you will be fetching Data as a list of om objects. Each om object will have an OrderDate property. It looks like those OrderDate properties are not proper javascript date objects. One of the ways is to iterate through the list and do a cast - something like this ->

```
 om.OrderDate = new Date(om.OrderDate);
```

You could format the date as well, by using $filter('date'), or by using other means.